# Parsing Json like structure in spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file with data structured like this

```
{'analytics_category_id': 'Default', 'item_sub_type': '', 'deleted_at': '', 'product_category_id': 'Default', 'unit_price': '0.000', 'id': 'myntramprdii201907174a72fb2475d84103844083d1348acb9e', 'is_valid': True, 'measurement_uom_id': '', 'description': '', 'invoice_type': 'receivable_debit_note', 'linked_core_invoice_item_id': '', 'ref_3': '741423', 'ref_2': '6001220139357318', 'ref_1': '2022-07-04', 'tax_rate': '0.000', 'reference_id': '', 'ref_4': '', 'product_id': 'Default', 'total_amount': '0.000', 'tax_auth_party_id': '', 'item_type': 'Product', 'invoice_item_attributes': '', 'core_invoice_id': 'myntramprdi20190717a1e925911345463393bc4ac1b124dbe5', 'tax_auth_geo_id': '', 'quantity': 1}


{'analytics_category_id': 'Default', 'item_sub_type': '', 'deleted_at': '', 'product_category_id': 'Default', 'unit_price': '511.000', 'id': 'myntramprdii20190717c749a96d2e7144aea7fc5125287717f7', 'is_valid': True, 'measurement_uom_id': '', 'description': '', 'invoice_type': 'receivable_debit_note', 'linked_core_invoice_item_id': '', 'ref_3': '741424', 'ref_2': '6001220152640260', 'ref_1': '2022-07-07', 'tax_rate': '0.000', 'reference_id': '', 'ref_4': '', 'product_id': 'Default', 'total_amount': '511.000', 'tax_auth_party_id': '', 'item_type': 'Product', 'invoice_item_attributes': '', 'core_invoice_id': 'myntramprdi20190717a1e925911345463393bc4ac1b124dbe5', 'tax_auth_geo_id': '', 'quantity': 1}
```

I am trying to parse this in Spark using scala and create a dataframe off of it, but not able to do so because of the structure. I thought about replacing the `'` with `"` but my text can also have the same. What I need is a key value pair of the data.

So far I have tried:

```
read.option("multiline", "true").json("s3://******/*********/prod_flattener/y=2019/m=07/d=17/type=flattened_core_invoices_items/invoice_items_2019_07_17_23_53_19.txt")
```

I did get some success reading this as a multiline text:

```
read.option("multiline", "true").textFile("s3://********/*********/prod_flattener/y=2019/m=07/d=17/type=flattened_core_invoices_items/invoice_items_2019_07_17_23_53_19.txt")
```

```
|               value|
+--------------------+
|{'analytics_categ...|
|{'analytics_categ...|
+--------------------+
```

How do I read the keys as columns now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is linked to the `True` value used as a boolean in your entries: this is not valid in JSON which requires [`true` or `false` as boolean values](https://www.json.org)

If your dataset is not very large, the easiest way is to load as text, fix this issue, write the fixed data then reopen it as json.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val initial = spark.read.text("s3://******/*********/prod_flattener/y=2019/m=07/d=17/type=flattened_core_invoices_items/invoice_items_2019_07_17_23_53_19.txt") 

val fixed = initial
    .select(regexp_replace('value,"\\bTrue\\b","true") as "value")
    .select(regexp_replace('value,"\\bFalse\\b","false") as "value")

fixed.write.mode("overwrite").text("/tmp/fixed_items")

val json_df = spark.read.json("/tmp/fixed_items")
json_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [analytics_category_id: string, core_invoice_id: string ... 23 more fields]
```

If you don't want to a temporary dataset, you can directly use `from_json` to parse the fixed text value but you'll need to manually define your schema in spark beforehand and do some column renaming after parsing:

```
val jsonSchema = StructType.fromDDL("`analytics_category_id` STRING,`core_invoice_id` STRING,`deleted_at` STRING,`description` STRING,`id` STRING,`invoice_item_attributes` STRING,`invoice_type` STRING,`is_valid` BOOLEAN,`item_sub_type` STRING,`item_type` STRING,`linked_core_invoice_item_id` STRING,`measurement_uom_id` STRING,`product_category_id` STRING,`product_id` STRING,`quantity` BIGINT,`ref_1` STRING,`ref_2` STRING,`ref_3` STRING,`ref_4` STRING,`reference_id` STRING,`tax_auth_geo_id` STRING,`tax_auth_party_id` STRING,`tax_rate` STRING,`total_amount` STRING,`unit_price` STRING")

val jsonParsingOptions: Map[String,String] = Map()

val json_df = fixed
     .select(from_json('value, jsonSchema, jsonParsingOptions) as "j")
     .select(jsonSchema.map(f => 'j.getItem(f.name).as(f.name)):_*)
json_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [analytics_category_id: string, core_invoice_id: string ... 23 more fields]
```

As an aside, from the snippet you posted, you don't seem to require the `multiline` option but if you actually do you'll need to add the option to the `jsonParsingOptions` map.

Comment: Tried this: 

    ```val fixed = coreinvoiceData
      .select(regexp_replace(coreinvoiceData.col("value"),"\\bTrue\\b","true") as "value")
      .select(regexp_replace(coreinvoiceData.col("value"),"\\bFalse\\b","false") as "value1")``` 
But I am getting `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) value#0 missing from value#11 in operator`

Comment: It's an AnalysisException: this means that when Spark tries to figure out the schema of your `coreinvoiceData` it finds 2 difference possible "value" columns and doesn't know which one you mean. It's an issue with how you create this dataframe.

Comment: Yup.. Got it Thanks.
Although, the solution did not help.

I tried `var  json_df = coreinvoiceData.select(from_json(coreinvoiceData.col("value"), jsonSchema, jsonParsingOptions).alias("j"))
    json_df = json_df.select(jsonSchema.map(f => json_df.col("j").getItem(f.name).alias(f.name)):_*)
`

But I am getting `null` in all columns of the dataframe

Comment: The solution works since you actually get a parsed DataFrame as columns. All null columns likely means the column names in the enforced jsonSchema don't match the column names you have in your json files. Like I wrote, saving a temp dataset and re-reading it is way easier to make work properly. Do it first at least to figure out the correct schema.